# Using the parameters that are read from excel in the API

Tags: katalon-studio

I have two parameters [username and password]. These two could be read from excel into the API. But when I use these values in the API, I could not get the response in the API. Kindly help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

I am using excel to read the parameters.

```
println ("...Fetching Username         : "+Username)
println (".. Fetching Password         : "+Password)
WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('SIT_BDA/LoginAPI',[ ('Username'): Username, ('Password') : Password]))
```

I wanted to use the username and password which are being read from the excel and get the response in the API.

Comment: Please, post the outcome of the above code (error trace, etc.).

Comment: What do you use to read data from xls file? Could you post some code?

Comment: @MateMrše : Thanks for the response. I could get the output I was expecting. I have set a variable for the response I received from the first API and used the same in the next API.

Comment: @plaidshirt: Initially we need to read the data from the excel under the option Data Files.Then in the test suite we need to bind the desired data. Then we can create a test case to read the same. This test case needs to be executed from the test suite where we are referring the Data Binding.

Comment: @plaidshirt  The code is as below:

println ("...Fetching Username         : "+Username)
println (".. Fetching Password         : "+Password)

WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('SIT_BDA/LoginAPI',[ ('Username'):Username, ('Password') : Password]))

Comment: @Asayadeepak : I answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read XLS you can use `Data Files` in `Katalon Studio`. Create a new one and set input file.
To write XLS file you can use `Apache POI` Java API, which you can set in a custom keyword. There is a detailed [tutorial](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/write-data-into-excel-file-at-runtime-during-test-execution.html).